# Low bandwith usage / low throughput on multiple http requests in a loop

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, networking, tcp

I am using **Node.Js v0.10.2** and process about 500 Links in a loop.
The http requests get stuck and i can see a drop of bandwith all the time.

On my 100mbit dedicated server, i only have [~4500KB/s throughput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1rxK.png). On my home computer with 64 mbit connection only 1500KB/s throughput.I used `slurm` for throughput measuring.

I am running a *debian 6* with *i7 2600* on *16gb ram*.

I also tried different configurations of agents and tried out Connection: Close / Keep-Alive, but there still was no improvement.

I really have no clue about where it is lacking...

> node [server.js](http://pastie.org/private/bgx7xc7qsxv0mohrczsm7q)

**/etc/sysctl.conf:**

```
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 786432 1048576 26777216
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 360000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2500
vm.min_free_kbytes = 65536
vm.swappiness = 0
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.core.somaxconn = 35000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 32000
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 64000
fs.file-max = 1000000
```

**ulimit -a**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127906
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 99999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 127906
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Are the pages all on the same site? Could the problem be that the site you're fetching the pages from is throttling you?

Comment: no they are all on different remote machines.

Comment: [`{ agent: false }`?](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)